# PHP: Can I get array functionality in method overloading (__get)?

Tags: php, arrays, get, overloading

What I'd like ti achieve is that when I call $obj->CAT[15];
the $obj would check if the property CAT exists if not, get the value on the fly

```
public function __get($var){
if($var == "CAT") return $this->cats->get_cat($cat_id);
}
```

so my question is... how to get array's value 15 from my example? to pass it to my get_cat method?

Comment: you can do would $obj->_('CAT[15]') and implement the _() method. i know it's changing the syntax, but it's will work (dunno if that works for you)

Comment: its not possible to know `$cat_id` since it will be provided, after `__get` returned a value

Comment: Sadly it's still in alpha, but php 5.4 will have array dereferencing, so `$obj->CAT[15]` will be valid syntax. See [the complete list of changes](http://www.php.net/releases/NEWS_5_4_0_beta1.txt). Also check out [this nice overview of new features](http://css.dzone.com/polls/what-new-feature-php-54)

Comment: @axelarge, `$obj->CAT[15]` is already valid syntax. The new array dereferencing stuff covers array-like values returned from functions, like: `foo()[0]`.

Comment: @IonuțG.Stan: would you mind to show me how? this is too advanced for me.. but I have to learn :)

Comment: @IonuțG.Stan Yes, that's what I meant, my bad :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have `__get` return an instance of [`ArrayAccess`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php) which will delegate to `get_cat` in its `offsetGet` method.

Something like this:

```
class CachedCategories implements ArrayAccess
{
  private $memcachedClient;

  public function __construct($memcachedClient)
  {
    $this->memcachedClient = $memcachedClient;
  }

  // Called when using `$cats[18] = "foo"`
  public function offsetSet($key, $value)
  {
    $this->memcachedClient->set($key, $value);
  }

  // Called when using `$cat = $cats[18]`
  public function offsetGet($key)
  {
    return $this->memcachedClient->get($key);
  }

  // Called when using `isset($cats[18])`
  public function offsetExists($key)
  {
    return $this->memcachedClient->get($key) !== false;
  }

  // Called when using `unset($cats)`
  public function offsetUnset($key)
  {
    $this->memcachedClient->delete($key);
  }
}

$cats = new CachedCategories($someMemcachedClient);
$cats[18];
```

Comment: In this case it would be much simpler to just implement a `get_cart` function as suggested by GolezTrol. But if you need to use `__get` you can try this one.

Comment: ArrayAccess: sounds intriguing, how do I do that?

Comment: @DS_web_developer, there's a simple example in the manual: http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php#arrayaccess.example.basic

Comment: LOOKS AWESOME! Thank you very much for your patience and time!

Comment: @IonuțG.Stan: not only it looks great but it is already working great!!! Gotta love StackOverflow :)

Answer (score 0):

```
class Test
{
    protected $cats;
    function __construct()
    {
        $this->cats = new ArrayObject(); // or your own implementation
        $this->cats[33] = "hey";
    }
    public function __get($name)
    {
        if($name == "CAT") return $this->cats;
    }
}

$a = new Test();
echo $a->CAT[33];
```

see http://www.php.net/ArrayAccess to implement your own list/map

hope this helps!

Comment: No, I don't want to pre-populate some other array...I have my values in memcached, so my get_cat method fetches the value from it on the fly... the whole point is not to use extra memory if not necessary

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly what you want to achieve, you could use a closure:

```
class kittengarten
{
   var $cats;
   function __construct()
   {
      $this->cats[0]='Jerry';
      $this->cats[1]='John';
      $this->cats[2]='Barack';
   }
   public function __get($var)
   {
      if($var == "CAT")
      {
         $array_of_cats=$this->cats;
         return function($num) use ($array_of_cats)
         {
            return $array_of_cats[$num];
         };
      }
   }

}
$kittengarten=new kittengarten();
echo 'The third directly accessed cat is '.$kittengarten->cats[2];
$cat=$kittengarten->CAT;
if (is_string($cat)) echo $kittengarten->CAT; 
else echo 'The third cat accessed using closure is '.$cat(2);
```

Output:

The third directly accessed cat is Barack

The third cat accessed using closure is Barack

Comment: I don't want to pre-populate the array since there are 3000+ categories in it...I have to think about scalability and this array would be initialized for evry app instance.../per request / per user.. the memory is suffering now... thats why I a trying to do it on the fly /per category

Comment: You do not need to pre-populate; $this->cats is in __construct just for example. The $cat(2) thing will work even if you populate $this->cats later.

Comment: Oh, I got it, you already have lots of $obj->CAT[15]'s and do not want to change this! Ionuț G. Stan's answer is what you need.